# AVFoundation change Swift code to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, camera, avfoundation

I found an example code of AVFoundation which is written in Swift. I tried to change the code into Objective-C. But I am not sure if I did this correctly, because the code does not work at the moment. Could you have a look on that please?

```
func initialiseCaptureSession()
{
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    guard let frontCamera = (AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) as! [AVCaptureDevice])
        .filter({ $0.position == .Front })
        .first else
    {
        fatalError("Unable to access front camera")
    }

    do
    {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)

        captureSession.addInput(input)
    }
    catch
    {
        fatalError("Unable to access front camera")
    }

    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_queue_create("sample buffer delegate", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL))
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
    {
        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
    }

    captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

My Objective-C code:

```
-(void)initializeCaptureSession {

self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = nil;

NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput;

for(AVCaptureDevice *camera in devices) {

    if([camera position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) { // is front camera
        inputDevice = camera;
        deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:nil];
        [self.captureSession addInput:deviceInput];
        break;
    }
}
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOutput = nil;
[videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_queue_create("sample buffer delegate", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)];
if([self.captureSession canAddOutput:videoOutput]) {
    [self.captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];
}
[self.captureSession startRunning];
```

}

The problem is, that in my case

`if([self.captureSession canAddOutput:videoOutput]) {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];
    }`

is ignored. I am not sure, but is something wrong with my **self.captureSession addInput:deviceInput];** ?

Best regards,
Nazar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with this line

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOutput = nil;
```

The `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` is not initialised and hence`canAddOutput:videoOutput` fails.

You can initialise it like this;

```
videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks bro. This worked! I also tried to initialize **AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = nil;** with ** AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [[AVCaptureDevice alloc]init];
** but this caused an exception. Do I have to initialize this too?